# DAX Error: Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, formula, dax

Im back again guys, with a new issue... I dont understand this power bi, its so easy on excel haha.

Im getting the following error:

> Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define
>   calculated columns.

```
SLASERV1 = IF('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad];"";
IF(OR('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="Crítica";'DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="Máxima");4-('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Horas totales sin Pending]*24);
IF(OR('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="Alta";'DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="High");8-('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Horas totales sin Pending]*24);
IF(OR('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="Media";'DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="Medium");24-('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Horas totales sin Pending]*24);
IF(OR('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="Baja";'DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad]="Low");48-('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Horas totales sin Pending]*24)
)))))
```

**POWER BI COLUMNS**

[image]
[image]

**How its done in excel (Column P is the result I need):**

[image]

```
=IF(K3<>"";IF(E3="";"";
     IF(OR(E3="Crítica";E3="Máxima";E3="Urgent");4-(Q3*24);
        IF(OR(E3="Alta";E3="High");8-(Q3*24);
           IF(OR(E3="Media";E3="Medium");24-(Q3*24);
              IF(OR(E3="Baja";E3="Low");48-(Q3*24)
 ))))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears to be with the first `IF` statement:

```
SLASERV1 = IF('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad];"";
```

You're returning text in some cases, and a number in others.

However: nesting `IF` statements like that is not the best way to do it - a `SWITCH` statement would be clearer. Something like:

```
SLASERV1 = 
VAR SLA_Horas = 
    SWITCH ( 
        'DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Prioridad],
        "Crítica", 4,
        "Máxima", 4, 
        "Alta", 8,
        "High", 8,
        "Media", 24,
        "Medium", 24,
        "Baja", 48,
        "Low", 48,
        BLANK()
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 
        ISBLANK ( SLA_Horas ),
        BLANK(),
        SLA_Horas - ( 'DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Horas totales sin Pending] * 24 )
    )
```

What would be better still would be to have a separate table to maintain Priorities / SLA Hours. Something like:

[image]

Create a relationship between this table and your fact table on field `Prioridad`, then you can create a calculated column using:

```
SLASERV2 = RELATED ( SLA[SLA Hours] ) - ( 'DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Horas totales sin Pending] * 24 )
```

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55396655/ for an example PBIX file.

Comment: How can I use the Switch? Those numbers you put are supposed to be calculated as I mentioned above `4-(Q3*24)` `8-(Q3*24)`, etc.

Comment: That's exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

that error is quite self-explanatory, isn't it?

Powerbi column expects singe datatype, ie Number OR text. Can't do both.

If you want a single column, wrap the else part in Format function like this:

```
format(48-('DIARIO Backlog de incidencias'[Horas totales sin Pending]*24), "")
```

More about format here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax

But I would suggest you rather create two columns, one with label and second with the number